# Calling a Function Inside a Loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I would like to ask if it is possible to call a function inside a loop using Javascript.

I would like to create a textfield which increments and decrements a button without using the HTML "number" input.

Is there a simpler way to normalize the function by 1 and use a loop instead?

```js
function increment() {
    document.getElementById("myNumber").stepUp(1);
}
function increment2() {
    document.getElementById("myNumber2").stepUp(1);
}
```

```html
Number: <input type="number" id="myNumber">
<button onclick="increment()">+</button>

Number: <input type="number" id="myNumber2">
<button onclick="increment2()">+</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about passing the id as parameter to the function:

```
function increment(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).stepUp(1);
}
```

and then:

```
Number: <input type="number" id="myNumber">
<button onclick="increment('myNumber')">+</button>

Number: <input type="number" id="myNumber2">
<button onclick="increment('myNumber2')">+</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `id` of the input in the function call:

```js
function increment(elem) {
  document.getElementById(elem).stepUp(1);
}
```

```html
Number:
<input type="number" id="myNumber">
<button onclick="increment('myNumber')">+</button>


Number:
<input type="number" id="myNumber2">
<button onclick="increment('myNumber2')">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers surely solve the task, but... it's highly not recommended to use 'onclick' and similar attributes to handle the events by JavaScript now (for example, see "[Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)").

The recommended way is `addEventListener('click', callback)`, because the code is more maintainable and clear this way.

See https://jsfiddle.net/zrx2xqgg/ as an example for your particular task.
The selector of input is passed as attribute to button.